# FS2 Stream exception handling not working

Tags: scala, exception, functional-programming, fs2

I am having a problem with FS2 and exception handling. What I want is that, given a `Stream[IO,A]`, when I map on it using an `f: A => B` that can throw exception,  I obtain a `Stream[IO,Either[Throwable,B]]`.

I tried the following, and it works as expected:

```
import cats.effect.IO
val x1 = fs2.Stream.emits(Vector(1,2,3,4)).covary[IO]
  .map(x => x * x)
  .map{ i => if(i == 9) throw new RuntimeException("I don't like 9s") else i}
  .attempt
x1.compile.toVector.unsafeRunSync().foreach(println)
```

It prints:

```
Right(1)
Right(4)
Left(java.lang.RuntimeException: I don't like 9s)
```

However, my problems start when I try to do anything with that `Stream`.

```
val x1 = fs2.Stream.emits(Vector(1,2,3,4)).covary[IO]
  .map(x => x * x)
  .map{ i => if(i == 9) throw new RuntimeException("I don't like 9s") else i}
  .attempt.map(identity)

x1.compile.toVector.unsafeRunSync().foreach(println)
```

Blows up with the exception and kills the application:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: I don't like 9s
    at swaps.fm.A$A32$A$A32.$anonfun$x1$2(tmp2.sc:7)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction1$mcII$sp.apply(tmp2.sc:8)
    ...
```

Even weirder, using `take` to have the `Stream` return only the elements that I know to be OK, still blows up in the same way:

```
val x1 = fs2.Stream.emits(Vector(1,2,3,4)).covary[IO]
  .map(x => x * x)
  .map{ i => if(i == 9) throw new RuntimeException("I don't like 9s") else i}
  .attempt.take(2)

x1.compile.toVector.unsafeRunSync().foreach(println)
```

Can anybody clarify why this is happening? Is this a bug or (un)expected behaviour?

**N.B.** This behaviour is present in FS2 **0.10.0-M7** and **0.10.0**

Comment: You should probably create an issue on their github or ask on gitter: could be a design decision which few are aware of. Generally, however, you want to wrap impure code (e.g. throwing) in `IO { ... }` and use `evalMap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is here:

```
self
 .stage(depth.increment, defer, o => emit(f(o)), os => {
   var i = 0; while (i < os.size) { emit(f(os(i))); i += 1; }
```

This is the code inside `Segment.map`. When you allocate the vector using:

```
Stream.emits(Vector(1,2,3,4))
```

fs2 will allocate a single segment. Looking at the code above of `map`, `os.size` represents *the size of the segment*, meaning, `map` will always map the entire segment size. This means that even though you asked you `take(2)`, we're effectively still mapping the entire segment.

We can prove this by changing the code a little:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val x1 = fs2.Stream
    .emits(Vector(1, 2, 3, 4))
    .segmentLimit(1)
    .covary[IO]
    .map { seg =>
      if (seg.sum.force.run > 3) throw new RuntimeException("I don't like 9s")
      else seg
    }
    .attempt
    .take(2)

println(x1.compile.toVector.unsafeRunSync())
```

The important part here is the `segmentLimit`, which makes the stream chunk the data flowing inside to segments of size one. When we run this code, we get:

```
Vector(Right(Chunk(1)), Right(Chunk(2)))
```

Is this a bug or not? Not sure. I'd consult with the maintainers on the Gitter channel.

Comment: This answer has the same code error as the original question

Comment: @Daenyth Can you be more specific? Which code error are you referring to?

Comment: Throwing an exception from a place where you're supposed to pass a pure function (map)

Comment: @Daenyth OPs problem stems from impure code. His question was "why does this happen" and not "what would be a proper way of writing this code?" and my answer points to the subtility of chunks. Perhaps the answer should include an ideal usage of fs2, but I don't think that's what OP wanted to understand.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that to use `fs2` you must write pure code. Throwing an exception isn't pure, so if you want a step in your pipeline that can fail, you need to make it explicit. Here's two ways:

```
import cats.effect.IO
val x1 = fs2.Stream.emits(Vector(1,2,3,4)).covary[IO]
  .map(x => x * x)
  .map{ i => if(i == 9) Left[Throwable, Int](new RuntimeException("I don't like 9s")) else Right(i)}
x1.compile.toVector.unsafeRunSync().foreach(println)
// Explicit Left annotation is so you can .rethrow if desired; it can be omitted or added later with .widen
```

OR

```
import cats.effect.IO
val x1 = fs2.Stream.emits(Vector(1,2,3,4)).covary[IO]
  .map(x => x * x)
  .flatMap { i => if(i == 9) Stream.raiseError(new RuntimeException("I don't like 9s")) else Stream.emit(i) }
  .attempt
x1.compile.toVector.unsafeRunSync().foreach(println)
```

Of these the first is preferable, because `flatMap` with `emit` will result in size-1 chunks which are less efficient generally. If you want to stop processing at the first error, add a `.rethrow` to the end of the stream.

Comment: https://fs2.io/#/guide?id=error-handling
States the following 
"Note that even when using handleErrorWith (or attempt) the stream will be terminated after the error and no more values will be pulled."